# How to using regex to match part of the string

Tags: c, regex

I want to use regex to match part of the given string. you see, I input a string of **name** and match with the regex, So, i want this **name** to be part of the whole string, at the middle, start or end, even the whole string, So, **How to write my regex in C**.

```
scanf("%99s", name);
reti = regcomp(&regex, "\b\w*name\w*\b", 0);
reti = regexec(&regex, "something...", 0, NULL, 0);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a C string literal to contain a backslash, then you need to *escape* it using `\\`:

```
"\\b\\w*name\\w*\\b"
```

Comment: you mean like "\\b\\w*name\\w*\\b"?

Comment: Absolutely. Exactly as I've written it.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, escaping is an issue, but also using the `name` variable instead of the plain string with `regexec`:

```
reti = regcomp(&regex, "\\b\\w*name\\w*\\b", 0);
reti = regexec(&regex, name, 0, NULL, 0);
```

Comment: Sorry, that "name" is the one i want to compared with, the name string of input is the one i want to be part of the regex, sorry i didn't make that clear. Already edited, thankyou